Mounting NTFS with NTFS-3G while using nautilus
I am using nautilus on Ubuntu 23.10. Whenever I plug in an external drive, it shows up in the sidebar. When I click the name, if the drive is formatted as NTFS, it throws an error with the following text:
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/myself/20A8FDE9A8FDBD7A: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
I have installed nfts-3g and am able to mount the drive manually via
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/my-location.
This works, but I want to be able to correctly mount the NTFS drives using nautilus (i.e. not necessarily doing it manually via terminal). Is there a way to force mount to always run ntfs-3g when mounting NTFS drives (and not whatever it defaults to right now)? I was under the impression that installing ntfs-3g would automatically establish a symbolic link between mount.ntfs and ntfs-3g. Could there be an issue with permissions?

Microsoft formats like NTFS do not support Linux ownership & permissions. Those are set by the mount. Is Windows fast startup up on. That sets hibernation flag preventing the Linux NTFS driver from fully mounting a partition read/write. And Windows updates may turn fast startup back on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

@oldfred , there is no OS installed on the hard drive. It is solely for files, it's just formatted as NTFS.

If you do not have Windows best not to use NTFS. It may need chkdsk or defrag that can only be done from Windows. Or if used with Windows last has fast startup flag set. You may be able to manually mount read only, backup data, and convert drive to ext4.

It shouldn't error out though, is the ntfs partition clean? Try and run sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sda1 (replacing sda1 with the actual partition), and if that complains / doesn't fix it then try and run chkdsk on the partition from Windows.

The comments are irrelevant IMO. Mount with nautilus is not working for me with a fresh ubuntu 24.04 install, but sudo mount of this partition in the terminalworks without issue, The question is which mount command is nautilus trzing to execute.
